# undefined data when pass php values with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This calls and changes the values

```
 <select  width="100" name="produto" id="produto-list" class="produtoInputBox"   onChange="getapolice(this.value);" <?php echo $permissao; ?> >
```

i have this function

```
function getapolice(val1,val2) {
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "caixa/inc/get_apolice.php?id='<?=$_GET['id']?>'",
  data:'com_id='+val1+'&produtname_id='+val2,
    success: function(data){
     $("#apolice-list").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Whit this i get com_id = "i get value" and produtname_id = undefined but if i change this line on the script

```
 data:'produtname_id='+val1+'&com_id='+val2,
```

I get produtname_id = "i get value" and com_id = undefined

Thanks for the help

Comment: your val2 is undefined check that if it has values

Comment: Show the code that calls the function. Also, no need to try and build the data string manually, just use an object and jquery will format it correctly: `data:{com_id: val1, produtname_id:val2},`

Comment: You haven't passed 2nd argument in function.

Comment: Write getapolice(this.value,2) and you will get val2=2

Comment: i don't want a fixed value thanks

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
   <select  width="100" name="produto" id="produto-list" class="produtoInputBox"   onChange="getapolice(this.value);" <?php echo $permissao; ?> >
```

to

```
 <select  width="100" name="produto" id="produto-list" class="produtoInputBox"   onChange="getapolice(this.value, '2nd value');" <?php echo $permissao; ?>> //missed your val2
```

Comment: <?php echo $permissao; ?> that is only to allow or disabel the drop down box

Comment: getapolice function has val1 and val2. val1 = this.value. val2 = ?